# Create a line break in a subscript-position term

Tags: amsmath, subscripts

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\theta} \bm{J}(\theta) = 
\mathbb{E}_{s \sim T^{\bm{\pi}}, a \sim \bm{\pi}_{\theta}} 
[\nabla_{\theta} \log \bm{\pi}(a | s ) \cdot  Q(s, a) ],
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

And I want to break `{s \sim T^{\bm{\pi}}, a \sim \bm{\pi}_{\theta}}` into two lines, not put it under `\mathbb{E}`. In the picture below, how to move the second part after the comma and stack under the first part?

[image]

How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Off-topic: To "snug up" the `\nabla` and `\theta` symbols, consider writing `\nabla_{\!\theta}`. The `\!` (negative thinspace) directive moves the subscript term to the left, i.e., closer to the `\nabla` symbol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting equations under a symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476270/putting-equations-under-a-symbol)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you do two things:

- Using `\DeclareMathOperator`, make `\E` a "math operator"
- Use the `\substack` macro to break the long line into two parts.

Both of these directives require loading of the `amsmath` package -- which you may be doing already.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\DeclareMathOperator' and '\substack' macros
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for '\mathbb' macro
\usepackage{bm}       % for '\bm' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} % define expectations operator
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\!\theta} \bm{J}(\theta) = 
\E_{\substack{s \sim T^{\bm{\pi}}\\ a \sim \bm{\pi}_{\theta}}}
[\nabla_{\!\theta} \log\bm{\pi}(a\mid s ) \cdot Q(s,a) ]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```